# addView is not displaying the items

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch JSON object from an Api and display it on a checkList on a LinearLayout. Even though I am adding the checklist View to the container it is not showing. Is it the case that I have to use  `notifyDataSetChanged()`, If so how can I implement it in LinearLayout.

Thank you . I do apologize for my english.

```
public class NasilYapilir extends Fragment {

    int index;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;
    List<Reciep> reciepList =  new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nasil_yapilir, container, false);
        index = getArguments().getInt(DetailViewPager.KEY_INDEX_TAG);
        load_data(index);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        checkBoxes = new CheckBox[reciepList.size()];

        populateDirections(reciepList,linearLayout);
        Log.i("we are in nasil yaplir",index + "");
        return view;
    }

    public void populateDirections(List<Reciep> reciep, ViewGroup container){
        int i = 0;
        for(Reciep recieps : reciep){
            checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(getActivity());
//            checkBoxes[i].setPadding(8,16,8,16);
            checkBoxes[i].setText(recieps.getQuantity()+ " "+ recieps.getUnit_ad()+ " "+ recieps.getIngredients_ad());
            reciep.size();
            container.addView(checkBoxes[i]);
            i++;
        }

    }

    public void load_data(int index) {
        task.execute("http://yemekapp.kuarkdijital.com.tr/v_recipe.php?id=" + index);
    }
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection URLConnection = null;
            String current = "";

            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);

                URLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                URLConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = URLConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    current += (char) data;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                JSONObject itemObject = null;
                JSONObject quantityObject = null;
//                JSONObject popularObject = null;

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(current);


                String item = jsonObject.getString("item");


                JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray(item);
//                JSONArray popularArray = new JSONArray(popular);

                for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {

                    itemObject = itemArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String itemsQuantity = itemObject.getString("items");
                    JSONArray quantityArray = new JSONArray(itemsQuantity);
                    for(int j = 0; j<quantityArray.length() ;j++){
                        quantityObject = quantityArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Reciep reciep = new Reciep(quantityObject.getString("Quantity"),quantityObject.getString("unit_ad"),quantityObject.getString("ingredient_ad"));
                        reciepList.add(reciep);
                        Log.i("quatityArray",quantityArray.get(j).toString());
                    }

//                    popularObject = popularArray.getJSONObject(i);

//                    DailyData DailyData = new DailyData(dailyObject.getInt("id"), dailyObject.getString("Servings"), dailyObject.getString("Title"), dailyObject.getString("CookTime"), dailyObject.getString("Image"));
//                    DailyData PopularData = new DailyData(popularObject.getInt("id"), popularObject.getString("Servings"), popularObject.getString("Title"), popularObject.getString("CookTime"), popularObject.getString("Image"));
//                    daily_data_list.add(DailyData);
//                    popular_data_list.add(PopularData);
                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
//            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }


   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class NasilYapilir extends Fragment {

int index;
private CheckBox checkBox;
private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;
List<Reciep> reciepList =  new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayout linearLayout;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nasil_yapilir, container, false);

    index = getArguments().getInt(DetailViewPager.KEY_INDEX_TAG);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    checkBoxes = new CheckBox[reciepList.size()];

    load_data(index);


    //populateDirections(reciepList,linearLayout);
    Log.i("we are in nasil yaplir",index + "");
    return view;
}

public void populateDirections(List<Reciep> reciep, ViewGroup container){
    int i = 0;
    for(Reciep recieps : reciep){
        checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(getActivity());
//            checkBoxes[i].setPadding(8,16,8,16);
        checkBoxes[i].setText(recieps.getQuantity()+ " "+ 
    recieps.getUnit_ad()+ " "+ recieps.getIngredients_ad());
        reciep.size();
        container.addView(checkBoxes[i]);
        i++;
    }

}

public void load_data(int index) {
    task.execute("http://yemekapp.kuarkdijital.com.tr/v_recipe.php?id=" + index);
}

AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection URLConnection = null;
        String current = "";

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);

            URLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            URLConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = URLConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                current += (char) data;
                data = reader.read();
            }


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return current;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String current) {
        super.onPostExecute(current);

            if(current.isEmpty())
                return;

            JSONObject itemObject = null;
            JSONObject quantityObject = null;

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(current);


            String item = jsonObject.getString("item");


            JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray(item);

            for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {

                itemObject = itemArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String itemsQuantity = itemObject.getString("items");
                JSONArray quantityArray = new JSONArray(itemsQuantity);
                for(int j = 0; j<quantityArray.length() ;j++){
                    quantityObject = quantityArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Reciep reciep = new Reciep(quantityObject.getString("Quantity"),quantityObject.getString("unit_ad"),quantityObject.getString("ingredient_ad"));
                    reciepList.add(reciep);
                    Log.i("quatityArray",quantityArray.get(j).toString());
                }


            }


            populateDirections(reciepList,linearLayout);



    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Code dumps don't usually make good questions or answers. You should consider adding an explanation of what you changed and why it should solve the problem.